# how to provide access in my database to another computer

Tags: javascript, express

> original: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
> at Connection._handleTimeoutError (C:\Users\Venkataraju\Downloads\product\product\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:205:17)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
> errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
> code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
> syscall: 'connect',
> fatal: true   }

create a tables in user then automatic mysql database also created atable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=ETIMEDOUT+at+Connection._handleTimeoutError+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. There is far too little information in your post

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.